# Продублировать содержимое тега в самого себя

Tags: jquery

пытаюсь продублировать содержимое тега title_box в самого себя, но не выходит.

```
<h1 class="title_box">Test 1</h1>
<h1 class="title_box">Test 2</h1>

    $('.title_box').load(function() {
          var title =  $(this).text();
          $(this).append("<span>"+title+"</span>");
        });
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
<h1 class="title_box">Test 1<span>Test 1</span></h1>
<h1 class="title_box">Test 2<span>Test 2</span></h1>
```

Буду благодарен за подсказки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас почти всё правильно и всё работает:

```js
$('.title_box').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).append("<span>" + title + "</span>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title_box">Test 1</h1>
<h1 class="title_box">Test 2</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное  )

Comment: Можно записать чуть короче: `$(".title_box").append((_, html) => "<span>" + html + "</span>");`

Comment: @Regent: век живи - век учись.

Comment: Regent не работае этот вариант